# Uploading binary App Store Connect from CodeMagic

Tags: flutter, codemagic

I am trying to create the release build of my flutter app on CodeMagic. The debug build went well but the release build had the following error during the Installing Dependencies process:

> app-store-connect fetch-signing-files io.flutter.examples.hello-world --type IOS_APP_STORE --create --issuer-id xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4e85-85c3-xxxxxxxxxxxx --key-id YYYYYYYYYY --private-key @env:AUTH_KEY --certificate-key @env:CERTIFICATE_KEY

Did not find any Bundle IDs matching specified filters: identifier=io.flutter.examples.hello-world, platform=IOS.
Creating new Bundle ID: identifier: io.flutter.examples.hello-world, name: 'io flutter examples hello-world', platform: IOS

POST https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/bundleIds returned 409: An attribute in the provided entity has invalid value - An App ID with Identifier 'io.flutter.examples.hello-world' is not available. Please enter a different string.

It didn't find the Bundle ID. I have registered the app on App Store Connect but I have not been able to submit yet because I don't have a release build. Why is the build process not finding the Bundle ID?

This is my Bundle ID in App Store Connect
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing you are trying to build with Codemagic via the UI. Go to the code signing options and where it says Bundle ID (optional), add your bundle ID and save the settings. In some cases, it seems that fetching the bundle ID is unsuccessful, but defining it there will clear it out.

However, make sure that your bundle ID in your project settings and the one you clarify in the UI actually match as well. If you are not on a Mac, then you can open up your project.pbxproj in another IDE, such as vscode for example and search for PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER, there should be 3 instances of that, and change that to your wanted bundle ID. In your case it would be com.omni360co.tonnah as per the screenshot - add the same to Codemagic.

More about iOS code signing: [ioscodesigning.io](https://ioscodesigning.io/)